# Pyspark ignoring filtering of dataframe inside pyspark-sql-functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Good morning,

I have a question about some pyspark-code.
Assuming we have a dataframe like this:

```
+---------+--------+-------+--------+
| p_key_1 | p_key_2| status| value_1|
+---------+--------+-------+--------+
|       13|      42|   True|      33|
|       13|      42|   True|      12|
|       13|      42|   True|     106|
|       13|      42|  False|       0|
|       13|      42|  False|      27|
+---------+--------+-------+--------+
```

`p_key_1` and `p_key_1`  are partition keys, but to make this example smaller, I did not vary them.

Partitioned by the two `p_keys` I want to add a column which contains the minimal of `value_1` over all rows with `status = True`.

I wanted to do this with:

```py
my_win= Window.partitionBy('p_key_1', 'p_key_2')
my_df.withColumn('new_col', F.min(my_df.where(F.col('status') == True).value_1).over(my_win))
```

My problem is, that the filtering inside the `F.min(...)` function is completely ignored, so that all values of the `new_col` end up being 0, resulting in this dataframe:

```
+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| p_key_1 | p_key_2| status| value_1| new_col|
+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
|       13|      42|   True|      33|      12|
|       13|      42|   True|      12|      12|
|       13|      42|   True|     106|      12|
|       13|      42|  False|       0|      12|
|       13|      42|  False|      27|      12|
+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

The dataframe I wanted to get looks like this:

```
+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| p_key_1 | p_key_2| status| value_1| new_col|
+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
|       13|      42|   True|      33|       0|
|       13|      42|   True|      12|       0|
|       13|      42|   True|     106|       0|
|       13|      42|  False|       0|       0|
|       13|      42|  False|      27|       0|
+---------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

So my question is:

Why is this not working and which alternative implementations are there?

Comment: Also add how the resultant dataframe should look

Comment: Added example of the dataframe I get and the one I actually want.

Comment: I think you need to use `F.when()` inside the `F.min().over()`, and not the `my_df.where()`.

Comment: `my_df.withColumn('new_col', F.min(F.when(F.col('status') == True), F.col(value_1)).over(my_win))` That should do what you describe you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me. If you want, you can post your suggestion as answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you require is to use `when()` instead of the `df.where()`.

Taking variables from your example -

```
my_win = Window.partitionBy('p_key_1', 'p_key_2') # your window spec

my_df.withColumn('new_col', F.min(F.when(F.col('status') == True), F.col(value_1)).over(my_win))
```

The `new_col` field gives the minimum of the field `value_1` only if the `status` field is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way how to do it:

```
(
  my_df
  .withColumn('temp_col', F.when(F.col('status') == True, F.col('value_1')))
  .withColumn(
      'new_col', 
      F.min('temp_col').over(my_win)
  )
  .drop('temp_col')
)
```

The point is to create a temporal column in which you store values only if status is `True` and `Null` if status is `False`. Then you take `min` of this temp_col and `Null` values will be ignored.